# Confused about Node.js skipping lines

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
app.get('/tasks/:id', (req, res) => {
    const _id = req.params.id

    Task.findById(_id).then((task) => {
        if (!task) {
            return res.status(404).send()
        } 
        res.send(task)
    }).catch((e) => {
        res.status(500).send(e)
    })
```

I am doing an online Node.js course and I am stuck on this part. As the course instructor showed, when you search with a nonexistent id, it should return an empty 404 error `return res.status(404).send()`. However, on Postman, when I put a nonexistent id I get a 500 error, which is different to the instructor's result where he gets the 404. Does anyone know why that happens and the code skips to the error?

Comment: Task.findById threw an exception, that's why it is not returning 404... you may look at the body in postman to find out what exception has been thrown

Comment: Try enabling break on all exceptions